# How can I make a collectionViewCell like the one on Apple's app Shortcuts?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to make a collectionViewCell like the one on Apple's app Shortcuts, especially with the random background colors.

Shortcuts app UI:

[image]

Comment: "Random background color"? Is your issue about creating a random color? Else they all seem to have some gradient.

Comment: yeah it's mostly about creating the random background gradients.

Comment: Are they really random colors, or are they using a pool of presets of gradients? An I see maybe only an clear to gray gradient (with maybe lower alpha) just above that give that impression.

Comment: The colors aren't actually random, since you select a color for each shortcut. What exactly are you asking about? Do you want to know how to apply a color to a cell? Or how to select a random color from a set of available colors?

Comment: I solved my problem what do you think of my approach using Hash Tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear, however I think solved my problem. I wanted to create a similar collectionViewCell to the one on the Shortcuts app and I think I did pretty well, here's what I've done...
[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06aqL.png)

I put the colors I wanted into a Hash Table and then generated a random key to get the pictures array and then created an extension to the UIView class to make the gradient and passed the index of the colors array to the gradient function from my cellRandomBackgroundColors(), here's my collectionViewCell class and the extension if anyone want it.

```
import UIKit

class MainCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupCell()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    //MARK:- UI
    let iconImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Folder")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()

    let checklistNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "List"
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 19)
        label.textAlignment = .left
        return label
    }()

    let remainingsLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "2 Remaining"
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
        label.textAlignment = .left
        return label
    }()

    let editButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom) as UIButton
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "More"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        return button
    }()


    //MARK:- Setup Cell
    func setupCell() {
        roundCorner()
        gradientBackgroundColor()
        setCellShadow()
        self.addSubview(iconImageView)
        self.addSubview(checklistNameLabel)
        self.addSubview(remainingsLabel)
        self.addSubview(editButton)
        iconImageView.anchor(top: safeTopAnchor, left: safeLeftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 36, height: 36)
        checklistNameLabel.anchor(top: iconImageView.bottomAnchor, left: safeLeftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 18, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0)
        remainingsLabel.anchor(top: checklistNameLabel.bottomAnchor, left: safeLeftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0)
        editButton.anchor(top: safeTopAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: safeRightAnchor, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 8, width: 36, height: 36)
    }

    //MARK:- Methods
    func cellRandomBackgroundColors() -> [UIColor] {
        //Colors
        let red = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9654200673, green: 0.1590853035, blue: 0.2688751221, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.7559037805, green: 0.1139892414, blue: 0.1577021778, alpha: 1)]
        let orangeRed = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9338900447, green: 0.4315618277, blue: 0.2564975619, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.8518816233, green: 0.1738803983, blue: 0.01849062555, alpha: 1)]
        let orange = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9953531623, green: 0.54947716, blue: 0.1281470656, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.9409626126, green: 0.7209432721, blue: 0.1315650344, alpha: 1)]
        let yellow = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9409626126, green: 0.7209432721, blue: 0.1315650344, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.8931249976, green: 0.5340107679, blue: 0.08877573162, alpha: 1)]
        let green = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.3796315193, green: 0.7958304286, blue: 0.2592983842, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.2060100436, green: 0.6006633639, blue: 0.09944178909, alpha: 1)]
        let greenBlue = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.2761503458, green: 0.824685812, blue: 0.7065336704, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.6422213912, blue: 0.568986237, alpha: 1)]
        let kindaBlue = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.2494148612, green: 0.8105323911, blue: 0.8425348401, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.6073564887, blue: 0.7661359906, alpha: 1)]
        let skyBlue = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.3045541644, green: 0.6749247313, blue: 0.9517192245, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.008423916064, green: 0.4699558616, blue: 0.882807076, alpha: 1)]
        let blue = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.1774400771, green: 0.466574192, blue: 0.8732826114, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.00491155684, green: 0.287129879, blue: 0.7411141396, alpha: 1)]
        let bluePurple = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.4613699913, green: 0.3118675947, blue: 0.8906354308, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.3018293083, green: 0.1458326578, blue: 0.7334778905, alpha: 1)]
        let purple = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.7080290914, green: 0.3073516488, blue: 0.8653779626, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.5031493902, green: 0.1100070402, blue: 0.6790940762, alpha: 1)]
        let pink = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9495453238, green: 0.4185881019, blue: 0.6859942079, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.8123683333, green: 0.1657164991, blue: 0.5003474355, alpha: 1)]

        let colorsTable: [Int: [UIColor]] = [0: red, 1: orangeRed, 2: orange, 3: yellow, 4: green, 5: greenBlue, 6: kindaBlue, 7: skyBlue, 8: blue, 9: bluePurple, 10: bluePurple, 11: purple, 12: pink]

        let randomColors = colorsTable.values.randomElement()
        return randomColors!
    }

    func gradientBackgroundColor() {
        let colors = cellRandomBackgroundColors()
        self.contentView.setGradientBackgroundColor(colorOne: colors[0], colorTow: colors[1])
    }

    func roundCorner() {
        self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
        self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    }
}
```

The extension to create the gradients.

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func setGradientBackgroundColor(colorOne: UIColor, colorTow: UIColor) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTow.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks Awesome!!

Comment: Thank you! Please, consider upvoting.